# Comparar un valor seleccionado distinto a 2 resultados

Tags: c#

Estoy atascado con una tontería, en un listbox, necesito que el método OnSelectedIndexChanged genere el evento cuando sea distinto a dos valores, que no sea igual a "P" ni a "E".
tengo el siguiente código

```
    protected void DdlAdmitedevoluciones_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        S2I_VisibleControl(DivFechaMaximaDevolucion, DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue != "P");
        S2I_VisibleControl(DivCodBarras, DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue != "P");
        S2I_VisibleControl(DivEjemploDevol, DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue != "P");

    }
```

Entiendo que habría que meterle un ||, pero no soy capaz de que me funcione.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muy buenas Adrián, no tengo muy claro que estas intentando hacer pero para aclararlo un poco seria interesante que indicases el código de  `S2I_VisibleControl`. De todas formas si lo que quieres es comparar el valor seleccionado con los dos que propones seria mucho mas simple, ya que desde el evento tienes el indice seleccionado y puedes acceder al contenido del `listbox`en esa posición.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo que quieres condicionar, es si el control se hace visible (seria el segundo parámetro de S2I_VisibleControl entiendo) seguramente te servira una condición del tipo:

```
a ? b : c ? d : e
```

Para entendernos :

```
S2I_VisibleControl(DivCodBarras, (DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue != "P" ? (DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue != "E" ? true : false) : false));
```

Esto a ? b : c vienea significar si "a" entonces "b" sino entonces "c".

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente usa AND (`&&`) para la condicional si tu condición es que no sea cumpla ni P ni igual a E pones. Si lo que quieres controlar es que no sea P o no sea E usa un OR (`||`).

```
protected void DdlAdmitedevoluciones_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool Admitedevoluciones_not_P = DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue != "P";
    bool Admitedevoluciones_not_E = DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue != "E";

    S2I_VisibleControl(DivFechaMaximaDevolucion, (Admitedevoluciones_not_P && Admitedevoluciones_not_E ));
    S2I_VisibleControl(DivCodBarras, (Admitedevoluciones_not_P && Admitedevoluciones_not_E ));
    S2I_VisibleControl(DivEjemploDevol, (Admitedevoluciones_not_P && Admitedevoluciones_not_E ));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo así, me he hecho un lío con el operador.

Answer (score 0):

solo maneja tu logica de manera separada,

```
//la condicion se puede simplificar pero la deje mas explicita
      private bool ObtenerEsVisible(string valSeleccionado)
    {
     if((valSeleccionado == "P") || (valSeleccionado == "E"))
     {
       return false;
     }
     return true;
    }

      protected void DdlAdmitedevoluciones_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          bool esVisible= ObtenerEsVisible(DdlAdmitedevoluciones.SelectedValue); 

            S2I_VisibleControl(DivFechaMaximaDevolucion, esVisible);
            S2I_VisibleControl(DivCodBarras, esVisible);
            S2I_VisibleControl(DivEjemploDevol,esVisible);

        }
```